# How to do similar type of columns addition in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to do addition of similar type of columns (total columns are more than 100)  as follows:

| id | b | c | d | b_apac | c_apac | d_apac |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 3 | 5 | null | 45 | 9 | 1 |
| bcd | 13 | 15 | 1 | 45 | 2 | 10 |
| cd | 32 | null | 6 | 45 | 90 | 1 |

resultant table should look like this:

| id | b_sum | c_sum | d_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 48 | 14 | 1 |
| bcd | 58 | 17 | 11 |
| cd | 77 | 90 | 7 |

Please help me with some generic code as I have more than 100 columns to do this for. |

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `sum` and check the prefix of your column name:

```
df.select(
    'id',
    sum([df[col] for col in df.columns if col.startswith('b')]).alias('b_sum'),
    sum([df[col] for col in df.columns if col.startswith('c')]).alias('c_sum'),
    sum([df[col] for col in df.columns if col.startswith('d')]).alias('d_sum'),
).show(10, False)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I wanted to have more flexible approach as my real dataset has 100 columns which may not go by this logic.

Comment: @surajjadhav could you share more about your 100+ columns name? It's hard to write the logic without knowing the pattern.